# Can xml.minidom parse broken XML

Tags: python, html-parsing

**Note**:
I can't use third party modules so bs4 and lxml are not an option.

I need to parse HTML with the 
Python 3 std lib. I thought xml.minidom would be the way to go but it doesn't seem to be able to parse invalid XML/HTML without throwing an exception like syntax error.
Am I missing something within the xml module that can do what I'm looking for?

Am I missing something in the std lib?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that not being able to use third-party modules is justified, you have a better chance with  [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html), which should give you a more low-level control over the parsing process.

`xml.dom.minidom`, I am afraid, generally, is not going to be able to parse a broken document.

Answer (score -2):

if you need to handle broken html/xml, I recommend you to ckech Beautiful Soup 4

Comment: As I said I can't use bs4 or any other third party module